# Restart code after choice not in 'choices' variable?

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to make a surprise program for my grandparents that generates a lottery ticket. (They're Spanish so most of the things in the code are.) If the user inputs a lottery name that is not in the choices variable., how can I make it so the code restarts?

Thanks in advance

```
import random
options = ("Bonoloto", "Primitiva", "Euromillón", "Gordo")
reintegro = random.sample(range(1,9), 1) 
loteria = random.sample(range(1,50), 6)
boleto = sorted(loteria)


choice = input('Que lotería quieres jugar hoy? ')
if choice in options:
    print('Tus numeros de', choice, 'son:', boleto, 'con reintegro', reintegro)
else:
    print('Esa lotería no existe!')
```

Comment: Use a loop - a while loop is a good idea - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a loop - A while loop is perfect here:

```
import random
options = ("Bonoloto", "Primitiva", "Euromillón", "Gordo")

reintegro = random.sample(range(1,9), 1) 
loteria = random.sample(range(1,50), 6)
boleto = sorted(loteria)

while True:
    choice = input('Que lotería quieres jugar hoy? ')
    if choice in options:
        print('Tus numeros de', choice, 'son:', boleto, 'con reintegro', reintegro)
        break
    else:
        print('Esa lotería no existe!')
```

This code will continue to ask for a lottery name until they choose one in the list

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you also know how I can do it so it generates a custom number of tickets?

Comment: I would wrap the code that actually generates the tickets in a function - and then call that function multiple times as required.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a loop and break the loop when successful.

```
while True:
    choice = input('Que lotería quieres jugar hoy? ')
    if choice in options:
        print('Tus numeros de', choice, 'son:', boleto, 'con reintegro', reintegro)
        break
    else:
        print('Esa lotería no existe!')
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how I could either restart the code on request (by asking the user if they want to restart) or how to generate more than one ticket? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MadeByAlvaropop Put all the code in a loop.  Check for the restart option.